# iOS/Android - Sending Push Notifications To Users Based on Database Data Change?

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am using Firebase to store real-time data and I want to be able to send notifications to users of my iOS and Android app in case certain data is changed.  For example, I want to send a push notification when order status has changed to delivered.  The app doesn't have to be running in the background or foreground.  Is there a way to do that using Firebase or I have to look at other alternatives like OneSignal?

Let me know,
Anas

Comment: You mean that the app could be forced closed by user? 3rd party push notification management system can't control that. It should have any extra work by one! push notification receives regardless of the app status closed/background or foreground.

Comment: @hasan83  I know that I can send push notifications regardless of the app status.  But I want these notifications to be sent automatically when data in my database is updated even when the app is not running

Comment: does the following helps? search for the "Child Changed" title: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: @hasan83 Unfortunately, it doesn't.  First of all, the link is for the old Firebase.  Firebase has moved here :https://firebase.google.com.  Secondly, I know how to handle data read, but I want to be able to send push notifications when data is changed without having the app online reading for changes.

Comment: did you read the following article? https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Comment: @hasan83 Thanks, but I know how to do it.  I want to be able to send a notification to a specific device programmatically when certain data in my Firebase database is updated.  What steps do I need to take?

Comment: First sorry for posting un related stuff. But noone is answering any way. I guess u need to investigate firebase for servers.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350202/push-notifications-with-firebase-and-onesignal