# Push Notifications with Firebase and OneSignal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onesignal

I'm looking for some guidance.

I'm using Firebase as the backend server for an app I'm building and I would like to alert users when somebody has either liked or disliked some content the user generated.

I understand that Firebase offers cloud messaging through which I can target very specific users and send updates to them; I have implemented that functionality. However, I would like to send updates based on changes in the database, and, as far as I understand, FCM is not built for this purpose.

I have come across OneSignal and it seems promising. Has anybody implemented this with Firebase and could it do what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have it set upon such a way that when a message is send by a user to another user, a notification is also send via OneSignal. You just need to store the OneSignal userId in a node with the firebase user UID. 
I you like someone's content, then that would also send a notification out directly to the other user.